# Redirect Firefox extension updates to official add-ons site?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Now that Mozilla requires Firefox extensions to be signed, I've decided to only host my personal extensions at the official [Add-ons for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) (AMO) site. Previously, I hosted my extensions at my personal website, using the requisite [update manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extension_Versioning,_Update_and_Compatibility) machinery.

I'd like to redirect users who installed my extensions directly from my personal website to the new versions at AMO. I was under the impression that if I released an update of my extension *without* the custom `updateURL` in the extension's manifest, that it would check AMO by default. That doesn't seem to be the case, however.

How can I make it so that users who installed my extension via my personal site can get updates going forward from the official add-ons site? Are they essentially forced to uninstall / reinstall to pick up this change? Or can I trigger it somehow?

I should point out that the extension ID for my extension is the same, regardless of my distribution point. This is one reason I thought that simply removing the `updateURL` from the installer manifest would do the right thing.

**Update:** Here's further details on the scenario I'm trying to solve:

1. User installed version 2.6.5 of my extension from my personal website some time in the past.
2. I released version 2.6.6 of the extension on my personal website, removing the `updateURL` node from that version's installer manifest in the process.
3. I release version 2.6.7 of the extension on AMO only. I expect that the user from step 1 should be able to automatically upgrade their install to 2.6.7, **but this isn't the case**. It's as if Firefox doesn't know to check AMO for that given extension, even though the extension ID is the same.

**Update 2**: My installer manifest for version 2.6.6 contained the `updateKey` node, but not the `updateURL` node. When I remove the `updateKey` from the installer manifest, repackage the extension, and install it, the updates available at AMO are then found successfully. This shifts the problem, however, to the update manifest on my website. In order for an extension update to be found via my website, it needs the `updateKey` (unless I'm missing something obvious). How can I automatically push an update to an extension that (a) isn't hosted on AMO and (b) has neither an `updateKey` or an `updateURL` present in its installer manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your extension hosted on AMO, it will be automatically updated for the user (unless the user has 'Automatic updates' turned off for your particular add-on via *Tools > Add-ons > Extensions > (your extension) > More*.

And yes, you should remove the `updateURL` tag from your `install.rdf` file.

You can find more information at the [MDM site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#updateURL).

Comment: I do have my extension hosted at AMO, but automatic updates aren't detected for my extension. I'll update my question with further details to try and clarify what I'm looking to do.

Comment: You say the user originally installed v2.6.5.  Did he every get the v2.6.6 update from your website?  If not, his version still has the updateURL pointing to your website and will never look to AMO for updates.

Comment: Yes, the user (me, in this case), got the 2.6.6 update from my website. When I tell the extension to update a second time, it claims no updates are available, even though version 2.6.7 is posted on AMO. [Here's the link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/colt/?src=ss) to my extension on AMO, and here's the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jgbishop/colt) if you want to look at the source.

Comment: Now that I look at it, I see that I took out the `updateURL`, but I didn't remove the `updateKey` from the installer manifest. Perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: Can you supply a link to the v2.6.6?  I'll try it on my end.

Comment: Thanks Chuck for the indepth help. Jonah, the updates should be delivered with 24 hours after they are approved.

Comment: Here's [a download link](http://www.borngeek.com/downloads/colt/colt_2_6_6.xpi) to 2.6.6. Firefox 42 now seems to block installation of this extension (at least for me), so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Ok ... I installed v2.6.6 in Fx 42.0 (it complained about it being unverified, but it did install).  It would not, however, update through AMO.  I then remove the `updateKey` from install.rdf, re-installed it and had Fx look for updates.  It did find v2.6.7 and installed it.  So the problem does seem to be the inclusion of `updateKey` that's keeping AMO from updating.

Comment: Any idea how I can go about pushing an update to my users that has neither an `updateURL` nor an `updateKey`? I know https is an option, but I don't have any of that set up at my site. If the solution is simply to have users manually upgrade (by reinstalling from AMO), then so be it.

Comment: Once you remove `updateURL` and `updateKey` the only way for your users to update automatically is through the Fx daily (or so) phone home process. However, once the extension is signed you can host it on both AMO and your homepage (I do that with all my extensions) but the auto-update can only come from AMO.  You don't need `https` - I don't use it and it's never been an issue. The biggest problem is notifying your users that the update is available.  I have my own support forum where I announce new betas and stable releases.  I also mention it on AMO and my extension's respective homepages.

Comment: If your add-on is popular with techies, you can also announce it on [MozillaZine](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewforum.php?f=19) (where many Fx geeks visit frequently - myself included).

Comment: So, once I've removed `updateKey` and `updateURL`, what do I do with my custom update manifest on my site? Is there some magic incantation to point to a signed variant of the extension on my personal website? I thought distribution anywhere other than AMO was forbidden... Thanks for all your help, by the way; you'll definitely be getting my bounty!

Comment: Just remove the update manifest from your website.  It's not needed.  You can offer your add-on on your website as a link to the .xpi (which you download from AMO and place in your domain).  [Here's an example](http://softwarebychuck.com/febe/febe.html#latest) of how I did it. (You may have to modify your  `.htaccess` to make it downloadable.  I can help you out if you don't know how or don't feel comfortable doing it.)

Comment: It's not forbidden ... I've been doing it for over a decade.  As long as it's signed it doesn't matter where it comes from.